# node-inspector failing to start

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, node-inspector

Command ran:

```
$ node-debug --web-port=8090 myfile.js
```

This returned following:

> Node Inspector is now available from
>   http://127.0.0.1:8090/debug?port=5858 Debugging myfile.js
>
> debugger listening on port 5858 Command failed:
>   [971:971:0223/200200:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(210)] Gtk: cannot open
>   display: :0 Error: cannot open display: :0 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461:
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461:
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461:
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461:
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found
>   [1005:1005:0223/200201:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(210)] Gtk: cannot
>   open display: :0 /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2:
>   not found /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found xdg-open: no
>   method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/debug?port=5858'
>   Please open the URL manually in Chrome/Chromium/Opera or similar browser

Visiting http://127.0.0.1:8090/debug?port=5858, however, returns, "Connection Refused" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `-c` option to prevent `node-debug` from opening the browser:

```
$ node-debug -c --web-port 8090 myfile.js
```

IIRC `node-debug` discards error messages from inspector backend. You can try to run the backend manually to verify that it starts correctly.

```
$ node-inspector --web-port 8090
# in another terminal tab/window
$ node --debug myfile.js
```

Comment: Giving -c doesn't give that error as its not opening any browser now but the problem of not being able to see UI of node inspector on visiting http://127.0.0.1:8090/debug?port=5858 still persists.

Comment: Your second set of commands solved my problem i.e. running node-inspector and node --debug separately. Thanks.